# How to smooth a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have this terrain mesh with some mountains, but also some plains between the mountains.

[image: mesh]

I would like to smooth out the plains, because when 3D printed they cause a lot of unnecessary walls:

[image: sliced]

Basically if you'd represent this as an image with white = high and black = low, I'd like to blur the image.

I tried the "Smooth Laplacian" modifier which does nothing and the "Smooth" modifier which does this:

[image: smoothed]

Comment: Try the Smooth command in edit mode in 2.79 hit W, in 2.8 hit Ctrl+v. Or use the smooth sculpt brush in sculpt mode.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was something wrong with my mesh (although it looked completely fine in edit mode). I activated the *Mesh: 3D Print Toolbox* add-on and then used the *Make Manifold* button on my mesh. After that all the smoothing tools (*Smooth* modifier, *Smooth* sculpt brush) began to work properly.